# why my Image doesn't appear in UIImage View?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I made a view controller to show up an Image, the image will be shown up after the user press the right button item in the `checkOutVC` like this

[image]

the image should be appear in the `ReusableImageDisplayVC` like this

[image]

I send the image from `checkOutVC` to `ReusableImageDisplayVC`, the code I use for those view controller are below :

```
class CheckoutTVC: UITableViewController {

 @IBAction func openImageBarButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        var displayedImage = UIImage()
        let imagePath = "https://***.jpg"
        let urlImage = URL(string: imagePath)

        NetworkingService.fetchData(url: urlImage!) { (result) in
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            switch result {
            case .failure(let error) :
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, actionTitle: "Back")
            case .success (let imageData):
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                displayedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            }
        }


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popup = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageDisplay") as! ReusableImageDisplayVC
        popup.photo = displayedImage


        present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

and the code in ReusableImageDisplayVC are below

```
class ReusableImageDisplayVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImagePhoto: UIImageView!
    var photo : UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if photo == nil {
            print("photo is nil")
        } else {
            print("photo is not nil")
        }

        print(photo!)

        ImagePhoto.image = photo!


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReusableImageDisplayVC.tapFunction(sender:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        ImagePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }



    @objc func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

as we can see in the `ReusableImageDisplayVC` I am trying to make sure that  the UIImage from previous VC is available, and in the debugging area it is printed

> photo is not nil,
>    UIImage: 0x6040008bde20, {0, 0}

I have also assigned to the ImageView  `ImagePhoto.image = photo!`

but why when I run the app, it doesn't appear?

but if I hard code the downloading image process stright in the ReusableImageDisplayVC like the code below, the image will appear

```
class ReusableImageDisplayVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImagePhoto: UIImageView!
    var photo : UIImage?
    var something : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imagePath = "https://***.jpg"
        let urlImage = URL(string: imagePath)

        NetworkingService.fetchData(url: urlImage!) { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .failure(let error) :
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, actionTitle: "Back")
            case .success (let imageData):
               self.ImagePhoto.image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            }
        }


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReusableImageDisplayVC.tapFunction(sender:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        ImagePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }



    @objc func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

what went wrong in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`displayedImage` isn't set yet when you present the `ReusableImageDisplayVC` view controller. This is because you're presenting the view controller before the async call is finished. Try this instead:

```
@IBAction func openImageBarButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    NetworkingService.fetchData(url: urlImage!) { [weak self] (result) in
        var displayedImage = UIImage()
        let imagePath = "https://example.com/someimage.jpg"
        let urlImage = URL(string: imagePath)

        self?.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        switch result {
        case .failure(let error) :
            self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self?.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, actionTitle: "Back")
            return //return instead of presenting ReusableImageDisplayVC 
        case .success (let imageData):
            self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            displayedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popup = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageDisplay") as! ReusableImageDisplayVC
        popup.photo = displayedImage

        self?.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

(note the use of `[weak self]`, `self?`, and `return` in the `fetchData` completion handler)

Comment: sorry I am a beginner, the use of [weak self] and  self? are to prevent memory leaks isn't it ?

Comment: yes, `[weak self]` makes every reference to `self` in the closure a weak reference, which is why you have to use `self?` instead of `self` (`self` could be nil). This way, the block won't hold a strong reference to `self`. In cases where you have async code in a VC, there are sometimes situations where the VC might be dismissed before the async code completes. You don't won't the closure holding a strong reference to something that's no longer in use (memory leak)